# Operator shift overflow ? and UInt64

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to convert an objective-c project to c# .net and it was working great a few month ago but now I updated something and it gives me bad values. Maybe you will see what I'm doing wrong.

This is the original function from https://github.com/magiconair/map2sqlite/blob/master/map2sqlite.m

```
uint64_t RMTileKey(int tileZoom, int tileX, int tileY)
{
        uint64_t zoom = (uint64_t) tileZoom & 0xFFLL; // 8bits, 256 levels
        uint64_t x = (uint64_t) tileX & 0xFFFFFFFLL;  // 28 bits
        uint64_t y = (uint64_t) tileY & 0xFFFFFFFLL;  // 28 bits

        uint64_t key = (zoom << 56) | (x << 28) | (y << 0);

        return key;
}
```

My buggy .net version :

```
public UInt64 RMTileKey(int tileZoom, int tileX, int tileY)
{
    UInt64 zoom = (UInt64)tileZoom & 0xFFL; // 8bits, 256 levels
    UInt64 x = (UInt64)tileX & 0xFFFFFFFL;  // 28 bits
    UInt64 y = (UInt64)tileY & 0xFFFFFFFL;  // 28 bits

    UInt64 key = (zoom << 56) | (x << 28) | (y << 0);

    return key;
}
```

The parameters are : tileZoom = 1, tileX = 32, tileY = 1012

UInt64 key = (zoom << 56) | (x << 28) | (y << 0); gives me an incredibly big number.

Precisely :

if zoom = 1, it gives me zoom << 56 = 72057594037927936

if x = 32, it gives me (x << 28) = 8589934592

Maybe 0 was the result before ?

I checked the doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f96c63ed(v=vs.110).aspx and it is said :

> If the type is unsigned, they are set to 0. Otherwise, they are filled with copies of the sign bit. For left-shift operators without overflow, the statement

In my case it seems I get an overflow when using unsigned type or maybe my .net conversion is bad ?

Comment: Those numbers look about right to me. Why are you not *expecting* big numbers out?

Comment: 1 << 56 = 2^56 = very big number...

Comment: @vines At a guess I'd say it's about 72057594037927936 :p

Comment: running your code doesn't give me an overflow error...the answer is `72057602627862528`...what were you expecting?

Comment: Btw I would avoid casting directly from `Int32` to `UInt64` since that doesn't state explicitly how to treat negative values. Use `(UInt64)(Int64)i` or `(UInt64)(UInt32)i` to clarify your intent or validate the parameters to enforce they're never negative. It's not really a problem in your code since you mask it out anyways, but IMO it's bad style.

Comment: ok so the problem seems to be else where :( I continue investigating.

Comment: There is no overflow... what this code does is to store 3 numbers in one (the resulting number does not mean nothing until you do the inverse transformation). That's what is done to store RGBA colors in 1 integer for instance...

Comment: However, you'll have kind of an overflow if x or y is >= 2^28=268435456, or if zoom>255 (but the mask operation is preventing that)

Comment: Thanks guyz just by telling me no error with this function :) The problem was coming from the tiles type I was generating with gmapcatcher.